# How to write a Perl-style loop in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, for-loop

I just started learning Haskell. I was wondering if anyone could help me with a for-style- loop. In Perl this is what I can do:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $total = 0;
for (my $n=0, my $i=1;  $i<=10; $i++, $n+=50) {
    $total += $n;
    print "iteration:$i\t", "n:$n\t", "total:$total", "\n"; 
}
```

How can I get the same output in Haskell? Thanks.

Comment: Have you not made any attempt to learn the language and translate the code?  You'd learn more trying on your own then asking about any parts that are difficult.

Comment: The most straightforward way would be to translate it into a recursive function and then call it with the appropriate initial values.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @Thomas M. DuBuisson and @David Young. I can calculate sum of a range of numbers, but I need to work more on it. `fp2 = sum [x | x <- [0..450], x \`mod\` 50  == 0]`

Comment: @rnaeye Checking each value in [0,450] if it is divisible by 50 is very inefficient, especially since it is trivial to generate the range directly: `[0, 50 .. 450]`. There are no "for" loops in Haskell, you should generate the values purely: `scanl1 (+) [0, 50 .. 450]`.

Comment: Please don't misuse close reasons. This question is not too broad, it's just gravely lacking in prior learning.

Comment: `total = foldr (+) 0 [0,50 .. (10*50)]`

Comment: I believe that this question does have a reasonable answer: how to encode an imperative loop using recursion and an accumulator value. While this is not always the best solution sometimes it is the most straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like your code prints out partial sums. So lets's do that!

You iterate over `$n`s, starting at `0` and incrementing by `50` ten times.  Rather than doing this as a loop, a more Haskelly way would be to create a list containing all the values of `n`.

```
-- take the first 10 elements from the sequence that starts 0, 50, 100, 150...
let ns = take 10 [0, 50..]
```

Now we really want the partial sums of this sequence, so let's calculate that. We could write our own function to do this, but this is exactly what `Prelude.scanl1` is for:

```
-- calculates the sequence 0, 0 + 50, 0 + 50 + 100, 0 + 50 + 100 + 150, ... 
let totals = scanl1 (+) ns
```

Now that we have the totals, the only real work is to print them along with the corresponding `i` and `n`.  So we need our list of `i` values:

```
let is = [1..10]
```

Now we want to iterate through all three (`n`, `i`, and the `total`) simultaneously, so let's create a new list that does that:

```
let triples = zip3 ns is totals
```

Now all we need to do in our code is iterate through these triples and print our intermediate results. In Haskell, printing defines an IO action, and individual IO actions need to be combined before they are run, which is what `Control.Monad.forM_` does, combining the results of running a given function on each element of a list into one gigantic action.

```
forM_ triples $ \(n,i,total) ->
  -- use show to convert Ints to Strings, and ++ to concatenate Strings
  putStrLn $ "iteration:" ++ show i ++ "\tn:" ++ show n ++ "\ttotal:" ++ show total
```

Or all together:

```
module Main where
import Control.Monad (forM_)
main = do
  -- take the first 10 elements from the sequence that starts 0, 50, 100, 150...
  let ns = take 10 [0, 50..]

  -- calculates the sequence 0, 0 + 50, 0 + 50 + 100, 0 + 50 + 100 + 150, ... 
  let totals = scanl1 (+) ns

  let is = [1..10]

  let triples = zip3 ns is totals

  forM_ triples $ \(n,i,total) ->
    -- use show to convert Ints to Strings, and ++ to concatenate Strings
    putStrLn $ "iteration:" ++ show i ++ "\tn:" ++ show n ++ "\ttotal:" ++ show total
```

And it works!

```
% ghc SO26540775.hs && ./SO26540775
iteration:1     n:0     total:0
iteration:2     n:50    total:50
iteration:3     n:100   total:150
iteration:4     n:150   total:300
iteration:5     n:200   total:500
iteration:6     n:250   total:750
iteration:7     n:300   total:1050
iteration:8     n:350   total:1400
iteration:9     n:400   total:1800
iteration:10    n:450   total:2250
```

Comment: Not sure why you're explicitly ending `is` at 10, which means you have to specify that limit twice in the code (which the Perl doesn't).  Just `1..` would work fine.

Comment: Didn't feel like going into the min list length behaviour of zip3 in a beginner post

Comment: Fair enough, but now you have that redundancy to explain. :)  Maybe build the entire thing up as a zip of infinite lists and just take 10 at the end - then the termination behavior of `zip3` doesn't enter into it.

Answer (score 2):

Putting my code where my keyboard is, here's my modification of @rampion's answer to make it more DRY where the repeat count is concerned.

```
module Main where
import Control.Monad (forM_)
main = do
  -- take the sequence that starts 0, 50, 100, 150...
  let ns = [0, 50..]

  -- and calculate its partial sums:0, 0+50, 0+50+100, 0+50+100+150, ... 
  let totals = scanl1 (+) ns

  -- throw in a list of indexes for counting: 1, 2, 3...
  let is = [1..]

  -- and zip them all together: (1,0,0),(2,50,50),(3,100,150), etc.
  let triples = zip3 is ns totals

  {- Note that so far, all of these sequences are infinitely long.  Haskell
     won't try to calculate any members of them until asked, but it will keep
     calculating as long as you keep asking.  Most languages won't even let you
     define an infinite list, but that's where Haskell's laziness comes in
     handy; the fact that these lists are unbounded does not cause any extra
     work to be performed by the program.

     Still, we only care about the first 10 elements of this list, so let's
     grab those using take (which returns the first n elements of a list for
     some number n) and then iterate over those and print them out: -}

  forM_ (take 10 triples) $ \(i,n,total) ->
    -- use show to convert Ints to Strings, and ++ to concatenate Strings
    putStrLn $ "iteration:" ++ show i ++ "\tn:" ++ show n ++ "\ttotal:" ++ show total
```